# How to avoid rasterized vector to cover minimum area?

Tags: qgis, rasterization

I rasterized vector data(Lines) with QGIS.
The resulting raster covers minimum area, but actually I want it to cover more area for my purpose(See image).

How can I make the resulting raster data cover more area specifically ?

[image]

Comment: In arcgis you'd do it through environment extent